# Run a cron job every 5 minute only on specific hours?

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want to run some cronjob between monday-friday at 23.50 and 23.55. I tried some expressions but there is something wrong with my expression.

```
0 50/5 23-00 ? *  MON-FRI
```

When I calculate next days with cronmaker it shows;

```
1.  Tuesday, March 15, 2016 11:50 PM
2.  Tuesday, March 15, 2016 11:55 PM
3.  Wednesday, March 16, 2016 12:50 AM
4.  Wednesday, March 16, 2016 12:55 AM
5.  Wednesday, March 16, 2016 11:50 PM
```

Why it shows AM? I only specified 23-00 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 0 50/5 23 ? *  MON-FRI

> '-' specifies range. So, 0 50/5 23-00 ? *  MON-FRI means 11pm to 12am

Answer (score 0):

12:50 AM is the same as 00:50 or 24:50. 50 minutes after midnight. Since the hour is 00 and the minute 50 it matches your cron expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 50/5 23-00 ? *  MON-FRI
```

it can be write as below may fullfill your requirement

```
0 50/5 23 * * 1-5 ?
```

explain 1-5 means 1 = monday
... 5 = Friday
note: sunday = 0 or 7